# Which pronunciation of 'either' is preferred?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I pronounce 'ei' in 'either' like in German (so, like 'I' in English: /aɪ/). This is natural for me.

But I've heard people pronouncing it as 'eee' (/iː/), so which version is correct? Or maybe both are correct?

Comment: How is it possible that no one has answered this question with the word "either"?

Comment: @J.T.Grimes. I just came here to do that.

Comment: Either. (i.e. "Either pronunciation is acceptable")

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both are correct.

*Ee-ther* `/ˈiːð.ə(ɹ)/` tends to be more common in the United States, but it would not be wrong to use *aye-ther* `/ˈaɪð.ə(ɹ)/`.

Whichever way you choose to pronounce it, you should not have trouble being understood.

Comment: +1. note that if an american says /ˈaɪð.ə(ɹ)/ it sometimes is rejected as phony or trying to be british.

Comment: @hunter: +1 for your comment. Do most British people use /ˈaɪð.ə(ɹ)/?

Comment: I actually pronounce it both ways, depending on the situation. "You'll have to either do this or that" I would use the long i ("eye"), but "I would accept either one" I would use a long e ("ee"). Weird, I know.

Comment: @Wayne Yes exactly  - I can't think of another word where I'll slip between such distinct pronunciations so fluidly. It *is* weird.

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic case of dialects.

Both pronunciations are correct, however the one a person uses depends on their upbringing, their region and their preference.

Comment: If your native language is English, it all depends on where you grew up.  If you're learning to speak English, try to remember to use the same pronunciation for "neither".

Comment: I don't think this is really a matter of *dialect* (or upbringing). Vast numbers of native speakers (myself included) use both forms, and would be hard-pressed to even guess which one they use more often.

Comment: I deliberately and consciously say *Ee-ther* (and *nee-ther*) just as I deliberately always pronounce *often* as *offen.* I was taught in 6th grade how to pronounce *often,* and that's how I've always pronounced it, despite the numbers of people around me who "mispronouce" it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a bit to the answers already given,

'Most' native speakers tend to pronounce 'either' [ˈaɪðə] in sentences like '*either this or that*'. And pronounce it [ˈiːðə] in '*I don't either*' constructions. But then again, it varies from speaker to speaker. Both of them are correct and perfectly natural.

However, [ˈiːðə] is increasingly common.

Comment: In [this video](https://youtu.be/66aG5P0kQpU?t=1101) at 18:21, the BrE speaker says: "... we don't say **[ˈaɪðə]** of these **[ˈiːðə]**...".

Answer (score 1):

I think the British use ei-ther as the pronunciation, and the Americans use eee-ther.

I use UK English, but I use both forms occasionally.