# Pronunciation "either"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

It is **ai·thuh** for the British and **ee·thr** for Americans.

I am watching **House of the Dragon** and I encountered **ai·thuh** instead of **ee·thr** being used. It is an American television series, right? The question is whether Americans don't care casually or is it the region series is based on, or something else. I observed the same thing in **Lucifer**, Mazikeen always pronounced it **ai·thuh**. Even if she was not from this planet, she was in Los Angeles. Do the cast follow their own accent or do they go with an American accent when they are working in an American Show? It may not be a big deal for Natives to pronounce it casually as they wish but it confuses us (nonnatives) a lot especially me.

Comment: see https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60910/pronunciation-of-either?rq=1 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28/which-pronunciation-of-either-is-preferred?rq=1

Comment: Both pronunciations are used in different parts of Britain. ai-thur is more common in the south, and ee-ther in the north. In the US, also, both pronunciations may be found.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey What's the misunderstanding?

Comment: I actually pronounce is both ways and I am an AmE speaker. Go figure.

Comment: @gotube - that one pronunciation is used by all British English speakers ('the British'), and the other by all Americans.

Comment: I don't like "ai-thuh" as a representation of pronunciation - it seems to be half-IPA and half-English-respelling.  The average English reader would normally interpret "ai" as representing the "ai" of words like "laid".  It is only our knowledge of the two pronunciations of "either" that stops us from doing so.  I would suggest "eye-thuh".

Answer (score 2):

In British and American English, both "ee-tha" and "ai-tha" are [acceptable pronunciations](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/either). So your question is ill founded.  Both pronunciations are okay.

Generally a British dialect speaker will speak with a British accent, even if they are living in the USA, however they may "pick-up" some American vocabulary, or even eventually an American accent.

In a TV show for an American audience, a British actor may adopt an American accent to play an American character,  or the script-writer might use an American word, to avoid confusing the audience (even though the character is British and is speaking in a British accent)

Comment: "Generally a British dialect speaker will speak with a British accent, even if they are living in the USA," I do my best to speak like someone out of Deputy Dawg when I am living in the US, so that people don't call me a 'milquetoast Limey'.